# Axis2 web service conversion to Apache CXF web service

Tags: soap, cxf, apache-camel, apache-axis

Hi I am not too familiar with web services in general but, I am trying to re-create an old Axis2 generated web service using Apache Camel and Apache CXF.

In the old service, the SOAP body had the following shape:

```
<chi:processAMessage soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <A xsi:type="xsd:string">A message</A>
    <Code xsi:type="xsd:string">ABC</Code>
    <Complete xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</Complete>
</chi:processAMessage>
```

To re-create the old web service using CXF, I am following the Apache CXF example 'camel-example-cxf-tomcat'. In this example, SOAP bodies have the following shape:

```
<ns1:reportIncident xmlns:ns1="http://incident.cxf.example.camel.apache.org/">
    <arg0>
         <details>blah blah</details>
         <email>davsclaus@apache.org</email>
         <familyName>Smith</familyName>
         <givenName>Bob</givenName>
         <incidentDate>2011-11-25</incidentDate>
         <incidentId>123</incidentId>
         <phone>123-456-7890</phone>
         <summary>blah blah summary</summary>
    </arg0>
</ns1:reportIncident>
```

As I understand the CXF example, the node `<reportIncident>` is interpreted as the service's operation name, and `<arg0>` is interpreted as the service message's InputReportIncident bean.

How can I write my web service using CXF so that it interprets the SOAP body's root element as the service message's bean itself and therefore assuming a default operation name (as it is not included in the SOAP body)? Is this possible at all and, are there any examples that I can follow where all SOAP messages route to a common service operation name?

Thanks in advance,
PM.

Comment: Did you have a look at the WSDL of both services? The would contain XSD schemas that will give you a clue on how to do it. Generally speaking you would need to follow a top down design approach to design a message exactly like how you want to.

Comment: So far I have only managed to get around this by having my route consuming messages via the following uri: `from("cxf:/AServiceRoute?dataFormat=PAYLOAD")`. This however means that I am picking up the payload as xml and not as a POJO bean.

Comment: If you want to use POJO data formate, you need to generate the SEI from WSDL, or you write a SEI yourself for CXF to create a service module for parsing the SOAP message.